# Angular 12: reload header after login/ any navigation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, navigation, reload

I have angular application. In header I need to show notifications after user login like facebook , the notification unread count and on click notifications messages. Also after login need to redirect to timeline. `onSubmit` function in header ts file calls on login form submit.

**header TS**

```
 ngOnInit() {
 if (this.isLoggedIn) {
      this.GetNotifications();
    }
} 

 get isLoggedIn() {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn();
  }

 onSubmit() {
   
      this.authService
        .login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value)
        .subscribe(
          (data) => {
            if (data["status"] === true || data["count"] === true) {
             
              window.localStorage.setItem(
                "myUser",
                JSON.stringify(data["data"])
              );
              window.localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "true");
             
              this.router.navigate(["timeline"]).then(() => {
                    window.location.reload();
               });
              
            } else {
              
              window.localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "false");
            }
          },
          (error) => {
            window.localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "false");
          }
        );
 
  }
```

**Auth service Ts**

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
    let input = new FormData();
    const headers = { 'APP-TOKEN': 'xxxx' };
    input.append('email', email);
    input.append('password', password);
    return this.http
      .post<any>(`${this.serverUrl}api/v1/login`, input, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        map((user) => {
          if (user && user.token) {
            localStorage.setItem('myUser', JSON.stringify(user));
          }
          return user;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('myUser')) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

The problem is without  `window.location.reload();` the count/notification data not shows in header. After login, it needs reload after navigation to timeline. But `window.location.reload();`  gives me problem on production so I have used `useHash: true` in app-rounting.module.ts. Again that giving me problem in SSR implementation. So I need alternate way for reloading header after every navigation. As if I go to another header menu there also I need to use `window.location.reload();` to show notification data in header.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987293/refresh-header-after-login-in-angular2) way. But not works as expected in above flow.
How I can get rid of `window.location.reload();` and get same functionality/get notification data after navigation in angular without using `window`?

Please help and guide.